# Sqrt function invokes an error

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to do an aplication that calculates an equation. I need to use sqrt but I always get errors even after trying different metods that I've seen on internet.
This is my code:

```
public void calculate(View v){
            EditText number1text=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.num1text);
            EditText number2text=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.num2text);
            EditText number3text=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.num3text);
            int num1=Integer.parseInt(number1text.getText().toString());
        int num2=Integer.parseInt(number2text.getText().toString());
        int num3=Integer.parseInt(number3text.getText().toString());
            Integer del= num2*num2+4*num1*num3 ;
            Integer first=-num2-Math.sqrt(del)/2*num1 ;   -getting errors here 
            Integer second=-num2+Math.sqrt(del)/2*num1 ;  -and here
            TextView delta=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.deltatxt);
            TextView x1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.x1txt);
            TextView x2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.x2txt);
            delta.setText("Delta:"+del.toString());
            x1.setText("X1:"+first.toString());
            x2.setText("X2:"+second.toString());
```

I have imported `java.math.MathContext` and `import java.lang.Math`

Comment: what is the error you are getting ? Which line?

Comment: It is very recommended to learn Java before programming for Android.

Comment: *Which* errors? At *which* line? And... are you sure `del` is not negative (you should check that before calling `sqrt`)

Comment: As a beginner, you should tackle some beginner level questions first. We won't be giving our equation solvers just like that.

Comment: getting errors at        Integer first=-num2-Math.sqrt(del)/2*num1 ;
            Integer second=-num2+Math.sqrt(del)/2*num1 ; this two lines.

Comment: first =-num2 . Y have you put "=-" is this a typo? =- is not an operator. there is some mistake there. Same for the next line.

Comment: -1 Why won't you tell us what the errors are? This is actually the fundamental problem. You don't read the errors and don't think they have meaning. Read them, and work out what they mean.

Comment: Error is : "Type missmatch: cannot convert from double to integer"

Comment: Instead of -num2, use -1 * num2. or put -num2 at the end of the equation

Comment: Thanks, but still the same error

Comment: Ok. You are getting Cannot convert from Double from Integer because your RHS: "-num2-Math.sqrt(del)/2*num1" is producing a double which you are trying to set to an integer. Either you need to manually cast to make your code work (you will loose the precision though - NOT Recommended) or change first and second to Double type.

Always make sure when you are doing divisions or sqrt where float values are possible to either use double/float or manually cast.

Comment: @RahulDabas can you give me an example please?

Comment: look at the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a type mismatch on these lines as I understand it:

```
Integer first=-num2-Math.sqrt(del)/2*num1 ;
Integer second=-num2+Math.sqrt(del)/2*num1 ;
```

The problem is because [`Math.sqrt(double a)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sqrt%28double%29) returns a `double` and you are trying to set the result to be an `Integer`.

Why would you assign a square root to be an integer anyways?

You can probably just change them to doubles, like so:

```
double first=-num2-Math.sqrt(del)/2*num1 ;
double second=-num2+Math.sqrt(del)/2*num1 ;
```

---

Also, on these lines:

```
delta.setText("Delta:"+del.toString());
x1.setText("X1:"+first.toString());
x2.setText("X2:"+second.toString());
```

You won't be allowed to use `.toString()` on a double type. To avoid that, just remove it. Having strings in front of the `double` value will display it without errors.

```
delta.setText("Delta:" + del);
x1.setText("X1:" + first);
x2.setText("X2:" + second);
```

Comment: delta.setText("Delta:"+del.toString());
      x1.setText("X1:"+first.toString());
      x2.setText("X2:"+second.toString()); Now I have errors here:" Cannot invoke to String() on the primitive type double"

Comment: @user3450385 I've updated it. Check my answer. And please accept it if it works for you.

Comment: @user3450385 Click the checkmark to the left of my answer. Thanks and no problem.

Comment: after testing it, it gives me wrong values. I tried to change it to float but It doesn;t work. Can u tell me please how to change it to float ?

Comment: @user3450385 A `double` is just a larger `float`. Keep it as a `double`. What is some input and expected output? And then what's actually happening? I'll try and work through it with you.

Comment: Ok, I have edited the code. It was a mistake at delta. Not it is like this : double del= num2*num2-4*num1*num3 ;  and i've also added a if loop:if (del>=0) { ... else {
       System.out.println("No solutions!");.For example when I select that: num1==1;num2==6;num3==9 it should appear that delta is 0 ,and x1=x2=-3 but I get that delta is 24 x1 is -8.4494... and x2 is -3.55051...

Comment: And I also have a warning: " line breakpoint:MainActivity[line43]-Calculate(View)

Answer (score 1):

unless your number values are very large, you should use float or double, otherwise you'll lose the decimal portion at the /2*num1 part

Comment: Thanks but still the same error "Type missmatch:cannot convert from double to integer"

Answer (score 0):

Ok. You are getting Cannot convert from Double from Integer because

```
-num2-Math.sqrt(del)/2*num1;
```

is producing a double which you are trying to set to an integer.

```
Integer first =
```

You can do one of these 2 things:

1. Manually cast RHS to integer to remove the error:

   ```
       Integer first= (Integer) num2-Math.sqrt(del)/2*num1 ;

       Integer second= (Integer) num2+Math.sqrt(del)/2*num1 ;
   ```

   you will loose the precision though - NOT Recommended.
2. change first and second to Double type.

   ```
       Double first= num2-Math.sqrt(del)/2*num1 ;

       Double second= num2+Math.sqrt(del)/2*num1 ;
   ```

Always make sure when you are doing divisions or sqrt where float values are possible to either use double/float or manually cast.

Comment: delta.setText("Delta:"+del.toString()); x1.setText("X1:"+first.toString()); x2.setText("X2:"+second.toString()); Now I have errors here:" Cannot invoke to String() on the primitive type double"

Comment: sorry I just saw the message. You dont need to use toString function. Just "Delta: "+del will work.

If my answer helped you please +1 it. Thanks.